# How to find the exact xpath of an element (link) in an webpage

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Initially I tried with below code:

```
WebElement admin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Users']"));
```

and then also with

```
WebElement usrs = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/form/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/a[linktext()='Users']"));
```

The above codes didn't identify the object (link) in web page.

Please help me to resolve this issue.!

Comment: If you're hoping to get an answer to this one, then I strongly recommend that you add the relevant part of the HTML document!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try for the first 'a' element containing 'Users'.

```
WebElement admin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text),'Users']"));
```

or for exact match

```
WebElement admin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Users']"));
```

and

```
"//body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/form/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/a[contains(text),'Users']"
```

Comment: Hey Lensman, Thanks for your reply. I used the 2nd option "**WebElement admin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Users']"));**" and it worked fine.  _**Cheers**_

Answer (score 0):

If you're going the xpath route, make it easy on yourself.  Inspect element with Chrome then right click on the element in the chrome console and "copy xpath".  That will give you the exact xpath and you don't have to worry about any "contains" or anything else.  That's what the [1] is for.